# Why is url available in node without requiring it?

Tags: node.js

execute this:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(url.parse("http://x.com/"))'
```

and you'll get this:

> Url {   protocol: 'http:',   slashes: true,   auth: null,   host:
>   'x.com',   port: null,   hostname: 'x.com',   hash: null,   search:
>   null,   query: null,   pathname: '/',   path: '/',   href:
>   'http://x.com/' }

why? I didn't require `url` first so it should be `undefined`.  I find no documentation on it and what else may be available.

additionally, if I try to use it in a file, I do actually need to require it first.  why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `node -e` you're essentially using the REPL (read-eval-print-loop) which requires a core module by default once you use it. [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) is a core module.

See [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_default_evaluation) (Section: **Accessing Core Node.js Modules**) for more information.

Comment: ah.  a bit of #voodoo there